# QuickBlox 2.4.5 framework with chat

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am implemented Quickblox 2.4.5 (Latest one framework). So I need to implement chat functionality with using that . Can you please suggest me how to implement by step wise.

Comment: Download their sample project for iOS, and start looking at what happening there.

Comment: Follow this good official tutorial:- http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework